# Scale Listing inside figure

Tags: floats, listings, minipage

I'm writing a seminar paper about a Client-Server Application and I try to include the code I implemented. I do so with

```
\begin{figure} [H]

\begin{lstlisting} 


\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Die Datei package.json}
\label{packagejson}
\end{figure}
```

, so that it is mentioned in listoffigures. 
The problem I have now is that the listing inside the figure has to be on
one side an can't be splitted. I also cannot scale it to a certain size ( I tried using minipage ...) . Do I have to make two Listings if it does not fit on one page?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you have a look at alternatives (e.g. not using list of figures, but an own list)? And what's about `tcblisting` (from `tcolorbox`) as a alternative allowing pagebreaks? BTW: It would be nice, if you could extend your code to be a MWE.

Comment: I just solved the problem. I did want to have the caption inside the listoffigures and therefore had to put them inside the figure environment. After a research I did find that there is a thing called \lstlistoflistings that does the same for listings. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the problem. I did want to have the caption inside the listoffigures and therefore had to put them inside the figure environment. After a research I did find that there is a thing called

```
\lstlistoflistings
```

that does the same for listings. Thanks for your help :)